Is this performance of the two-way ANOVA correct?
Currently I'm doing an analysis of the electrical power, measured on the scalp using an EEG.  I have two groups of people (pathological and healthy), under two different paradigms (during morning and during afternoon). To do so, I'm assessing the statistically significant differences of the EEG signals of these participants in three different ways: differences between groups, between paradigms, and the interaction between both group and paradigm. The resulting image is here:(https://i.sstatic.net/wjulQjY8.jpg)
To perform the analysis, the data was transformed to meet the normality and homoscedasticity criteria. Afterwards, for group comparison, Student's t test was employed. For paradigm comparison, paired t test was used. Finally, for the interaction between group and paradigm, two-way ANOVA was employed.
My question is, for this data, is the head map correct for the interaction test? As far as I know, there should be more differences. In both groups and paradigms comparison, widespread differences appear, and as you can observe in the picture, these differences should only appear in certain regions. On the other hand, in the case of the interaction between group and paradigm, differences are not significant. However, I would expect some differences to appear in certain electrodes.
